# while passing id in url by using href in laravel css does not load

Tags: css, laravel, routes

I pass the id with the route, and the route is directed to the controller.

`<a href="{{URL::to('editShopKeeper/' . $shopkeeper->id . '/edit')}}">`

it fetches correct id and it goes to url ,but the page css and jquery does not load, because id is appended to url. Can anyone please help me to solve the problem.

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/fg/public/editShopKeeper/9/assets/icons/flags/flags.min.css"
>   flags.min.css
>   "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/fg/public/editShopKeeper/9/bower_components/uikit/css/uikit.almost-flat.min.css"

Answer (score 1):

If your link href attribute doesn't start with a `/`, the path is relative to the url you're viewing. try changing the css href attribute from `assets/icons/flags/flags.min.css` to `/assets/icons/flags/flags.min.css`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [base](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) tag to set a absolute path for loading CSS / JS.

`<base href="http://localhost/fg/public/" />`

As an alternative, you always can use the full path while loading the CSS / JS.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply....Sorry i am working in laravel,,i have already gave a path as

<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/icons/flags/flags.min.css" media="all">

Comment: As a full path you have to use `http://localhost/fg/public/assets/.......`. Otherwise, you can take a look at the other answer.